# Simulating network latency for localhost connection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, latency, ipfw

I need to simulate network latency to a program running on the local computer, connecting to a local service. Thus far I have tried [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) (a windows build of ipfw) which I got working after some trial and error. While it generally works, I can't seem to get it to filter localhost traffic. Even after adding a rule `from any to any` which affects external traffic, this makes no difference for local connections. I would appreciate if anyone knows how to simulate local latency using dummynet or a different tool. The tool should be able to simulate latency generically in IP packets, (TCP and UDP) and not be protocol specific.

Answer (score 6):

On windows 7 you should take at [Clumsy](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/):

> clumsy makes your network condition on Windows significantly worse, but in a managed and interactive manner.

[image: clumsy demo]

Comment: Yes, this is the right tool with visible effect. Unfortunately it does not have effect on 'localhost ping' statistics.

Comment: It tired Clumsy 0.2 with a local application connecting to a local SQL Server using the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` ODBC driver.  There was not affect on performance, even when turning on all functions at once.  (Nice animated GIF by the way)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just testing HTTP traffic the [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://fiddler2.com/) is pretty easy to use.  You just select the stream, flip to the AutoResponder tab, select "Add Rule", then right click on the rule and select "Set Latency".

Comment: Sorry, it's not http traffic.

Comment: @nitro2k01 then you should [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/661254/edit) and include the information so people don't need to go hunting in comments of answers to get all of the information.

Comment: I have edited the question now, but I would think that if people make extra assumptions about the question that are not mentioned in the post, that's their prerogative.